# MDK3 deauthentication attack problem: Every station gets disconnected

Tags: attacks, kali-linux, aircrack-ng

Having `echo >`'ed the BSSID of the AP into a file called blacklist, I run the following command to start a deauthentication attack:

> mdk3 wlan0mon d -w blacklist -c 11

The problem is however, that every station on every network gets disconnected. This include the desktop I'm sitting at, as well my laptop, even thus they are not connected to the `blacklist` AP.

What could the problem be - any ideas?

I've no problems with `aireplay-ng --deauth`, if that should be of any value.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the mac adresses you want to attack in a blacklist file,  and run mdk3 with the `-b` flag. Since you used the `-w` flag,  it disconnected everyone except the target.

Comment: Are you sure? Whitelist is for the devices you don't want to attack, right?

Comment: Indeed, I made a mistake.

Comment: So, I can't use a BSSID? But a BSSID is the MAC address of the access point, right?

Comment: My bad again,  I confused ssid and bssid. I edited my answer.